# Set a page as the default document root page

Tags: publishing-page, url-rewriting

At the suggestion of my SharePoint instructor, I've created a Team site collection on my SharePoint site.

In order to customize the layout, I've enabled the Publishing feature on my site collection and site, and created a new Publishing page to set as my site's default homepage. This all worked just fine, however I cannot figure out how to set this page as the docroot default page.

For example, I want to be able to go to http://www.mysite.com/ and be able to see my custom page. However when I go to that url, it keeps redirecting me to the page's actual location at http://www.mysite.com/Pages/default.aspx.

Answer (score 2):

The answer, though you may not like it, is that this is not officially supported in Microsoft SharePoint.

See: [Supportability of Rewrite and Redirects with SharePoint 2007/2010/2013](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2818415)

> **Rewriting** is actually changing both incoming and/or outgoing URLs. Any implementation of such rewrites is **unsupported** with SharePoint unless the path is symmetrical.
>
> For example, you can modify the path of a request, such as http://www.contoso.com/sharepoint/default.aspx, which is forwarded to the SharePoint server as http://sharepoint.perimeter.example.com/default.aspx. This is referred to as an **asymmetrical path**.
>
> SharePoint Server 2007/2010/2013 do NOT support asymmetrical paths. The path of the URL must be symmetrical between the public URL and the internal URL. In the above example, this means that the **/SharePoint/default.aspx** portion of the URL must not be modified by any external tool.

Emphasis Microsoft's. Specifically, exactly what you are trying to do is not supported by SharePoint.

Comment: How then, is a page in a newly created publishing site collection, which is located in http://www.mysite.com/Pages/, able to be used at http://www.mysite.com/?

If you go to Site Contents in a fresh Publishing Site Collection, and click on Pages, there you'll find the page that is used as the default page at the site's docroot.

Comment: You can set the landing/welcome page (http://techtrainingnotes.blogspot.com/2011/06/sharepoint-how-to-change-default-home.html), but it will still direct you to the actual page. The technical reason url-rewriting isn't supported is because of how the page paths are parsed in SharePoint, as the files are stored in the content database rather than as actual files on the file system.

Comment: You can still use URL rewriting, just YMMV, and it is not officially supported.